.NET IEnumerable what is it exactly?
I'm trying to understand what an IEnumerable<> is exactly.
I had thought it was just an interface saying the underlying data structure has these methods eg First() etc.
However I have tested  the the code shown here in EF which I would have expected to produce a TOP query in the DB as if it were running as an IQueryable, but it instead causes it to pull the entire table in memory to perform its operation.
 IEnumerable<EntityObject> m = DbContext.GetDbSet<EntityObject>();
 var x = m.First();

So does treating something as an IEnumerable force it into operating as an array or list or something?
Note I do NOT need to know how to optimize the query to be more performant, I am trying to understand why simply treating it as a different interface and using the same methods results in different underlying logic happening.

If something is IEnumerable you can use it in a foreach loop.  In other words you can enumerate it.

An enumerable could allow you to iterate infinitely, like this: static IEnumerable<int> Values() { for (int i = 0; ; ++i) { yield return i; } }

"what an IEnumerable<> is" and what EF does to support it are two things far apart.

Try m = DbContext.GetDbSet<EntityObject>().Take(1);

@HenkHolterman ""what an IEnumerable<> is" and what EF does to support it are two things far apart" IEnumerable and IQueryable both have a First operation, I would have thought that whatever the EF data type underneath is, the interfaces would be calling the same First operations so doing the same thing. How can the EF data structure be doing something else based on the same method call by different interfaces?

m = DbContext.GetDbSet().Take(1); this is going to do a top(1) because its not treating it like an IEnumerable, I already understand this, it would be the same as if we did a first or anything else. I'm not trying to generate efficient sql, I'm just trying to understand what an IEnumerable is as its not matching up to how I thought it should work.

You should be asking about the difference between IEnumerable and IQueryable https://medium.com/@shahrukhkhan_7802/understanding-the-differences-between-ienumerable-and-iqueryable-in-c-9dbc9ac145f3 IQueryable methods capture your intent so it can be converted to sql, IEnumerable methods are optimised for in memory execution. Treating an IQueryable as an IEnumerable will destroy its benefits.

Had a bit of a decompiler dig into the methods.
Far as I can tell the reason for the difference in functionality actually appears to be due to the fact that IEnumerables and IQueryables have different extension methods on them.
Looks like there is quite little going on in the interfaces themselves. This explains my initial misgivings as I couldn't understand how simply treating it as a different interface could effect the operations called on it.
The extension methods on the IQueryables cause it to execute the expressions it needs to query, whereas the Enumerable expressions prompt it to use GetEnumerator and move through them with MoveNext() which is what seems to trigger the query on the first call.

Yeah good try, however, I meant exactly it is. Anyway, Glad to see that you have also got that.


.Net IEnumerable what is it exactly?

As @ProgrammingLlama and @Henk Holterman already given you initial insight, However, I am trying expand a bit more.
As you may know IEnumerable is the base interface for all non-generic collections that can be enumerated, such as arrays, lists, or any other collection that implements IEnumerable. The main functionality provided by IEnumerable is the ability to iterate over a collection using a foreach loop.

So does treating something as an IEnumerable force it into operating
as an array or list or something?

Actually, simply assigning an IQueryable<T> to an IEnumerable<T> does not immediately execute the query and load the data into memory. It's the subsequent operations, like calling First(), that force the execution of the query and loading of data into memory.
The key point is that while the assignment itself doesn't cause immediate execution, the operations performed on the IEnumerable afterward will be in-memory operations, and certain operations like First() will indeed execute the query and load data. Any subsequent operations for instance, Where, First, Select are performed in-memory.
Now back to your shared code snippet, to ensure that the First() operation is performed on the database rather than in-memory, you should keep the collection as IQueryable. This way, the First() method will be translated into a SQL query with a TOP 1 clause, and only the first entity will be fetched from the database.
So, you could modify your code as following:
IQueryable<EntityObject> m = DbContext.GetDbSet<EntityObject>();
var x = m.First();

Note: Please refer to this official document for additional example for

"Actually, it forces the query to execute immediately and load the results into memory." No it doesn't. Just the assignment to a variable of type IEnumerable<T> won't do that. It's when you use the data represented by the IEnumerable<T> that data will be forced to be loaded. Yes, further operations such as Where etc will be performed in memory, but that doesn't mean the data is loaded at the point where the assignment to an IEnumerable<T> is made.

@JonSkeet Glad to have your feedback on this, I would update my answer.

Much better, thanks for the update.

Thank you @JonSkeet for pointing that and having your suggestion is blessing for me. Its been 8 years since I have been following you, your blog, github.
